# How to convert a list of numbers to jsonarray in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a row in following format:

```
row = [1L,[0.1,0.2],[[1234L,1],[134L,2]]]
```

Now, what I want is to write the following in the file:

```
[1,[0.1,0.2],[[1234,1],[134,2]]]
```

Basically converting above into a jsonarray?

Is there an built-in method, library, or function in Python to "dump" array into json array?

Also note that I don't want "L" to be serialized in my file.

Comment: `json`.. `dump`... yeah, there might be something.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to produce JSON output:

```
import json

with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(row, outfile)
```

This writes the JSON result directly to the file (replacing any previous content if the file already existed).

If you need the JSON result string in Python itself, use `json.dumps()` (added `s`, for 'string'):

```
json_string = json.dumps(row)
```

The `L` is just Python syntax for a long integer value; the `json` library knows how to handle those values, no `L` will be written.

Demo string output:

```
>>> import json
>>> row = [1L,[0.1,0.2],[[1234L,1],[134L,2]]]
>>> json.dumps(row)
'[1, [0.1, 0.2], [[1234, 1], [134, 2]]]'
```

Comment: @user3226167 this is a Python 2 question though; Python 3 does not have the two different type of integer objects anymore.

Answer (score 20):

```
import json
row = [1L,[0.1,0.2],[[1234L,1],[134L,2]]]
row_json = json.dumps(row)
```

Comment: dumps takes an object and produces a string.
```
>>> import json
>>> row = [1,[0.1,0.2],[[1234,1],[134,2]]]
>>> type(row)
<class 'list'>
>>> row_json = json.dumps(row)
>>> type(row_json)
<class 'str'>
>>> 
```