# How to convert data fetched from a database using python into a JSON string so that I am able to HIT a particular API

Tags: python, mysql, json

I exhaustively searched for my question on the web , but the closest answer I found was this:

[Answer for converting list to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795012/how-to-convert-a-list-to-jsonarray-in-python)

To be precise, I fetched some data in a variable in java using mysql-python connector module.

After I printed the variable,The fetched data looked something like this:

```
[(16,'abc@ail.com','lenbox','+91','16','ACTIVE'),
  (17,'xyz@ail.com','lenro','+41','17','ACTIVE'),
(18,'sdf@ail.com','meru','+51','18','NOTACTIVE')]
```

I want to use this data to hit an API whose URL and other details are known to me. For that the above data should be in a JSON string format.Please suggest a way?

I am newbie in python language and don't know so well about JSON.

Comment: import simplejson and create the json string by simplejson.loads(fetched_data)

Comment: thanks @MaNKuR that helped , although I faced a little difficulty in fixing the error : "datetime.datetime is not json serializable" . Please tell me a way to hit a particular API whose URL I know using this fetched_data